# Distance of a point from a line passing through the intersection of lines

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, analytic-geometry

I'm given a point $P(1, 4)$ and its distance from a line passing through the intersection of the lines $x-2y+3=0$ and $x-y-5=0$ is 4 units. How do I find its equation?

Here is how I tried to solve it,

Solving the two equations gives their point of intersection as $(13, 8)$. Then if I use the two point formula between $(1, 4)$ and $(13, 8)$ the equation comes out as $4x-12+44=0$, but the answer in my textbook is not similar to mine. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

The question as in my textbook is

*The distance of a point $(1, 4)$ from a line passing through the intersection of the lines $x-2y+3=0$ and $x-y-5=0$ is 4 units. Find its equation.*

The answer of the above question as in my textbook is $3x-4y-7=0$, 
 $y-8=0$

What am I doing wrong here?

What I think is that maybe I have to find the equation of line through the intersection of the given lines ($x-2y+3=0$ and $x-y-5=0$) and then use the perpendicular distance formula between that line, the point $(1, 4)$ (and the distance is also given) and then work out the equation. But how do I find the equation of line through the intersection of the given lines,

I know that it is given by $l_1 + kl_2 = 0$ where $l_1$ is equation of line one and $l_2$ is equation of line 2. But for this equation a condition is necessary to find $k$.

Comment: Note that the problem specifies that the *distance between* point $P$ and the *line passing through* the point of intersection of the given lines is 4 units. Then it asks for the equation of the line passing through the point of intersection of the given lines which happens to be 4 units away from point P.  What you seemed to aim for is finding the equation of the line passing through P and the point of intersection of the two lines (which isn't correct: one need only look at the y-coordindinates of the point of intersection, and point P, to see that *that* line has slope = 0 ...

Comment: Yes...I just saw your edits, you're going to need make use of the fact that the shortest distance between a point P and line l (p not on l) is measured along the  line intersecting P which is perpendicular to l.

Comment: @amWhy: But to find the equation of the line passing through the point of intersection of the given lines, I use the following formula i.e. $l_1 + kl_2 = 0$ but for this I need an additional condition to find the value of $k$, how do I do that? The point of intersection of the two given lines (as I found it by solving the equations) is $(13, 8)$ so should I put the values $x=13$ $y=8$ in $l_1 + kl_2 = 0$, get $k$ and then solve it? Is this correct?

Comment: The slope of which line? I know that slope = $m = (y_2 - y_1)/(x_2 - x_1)$ and $m_1 * m_2 = -1$ for perpendicular lines.

Comment: Ross is correct: you'll want to use the perpendicular distance formula to solve for the slope of the line passing through the point of intersection of two given points, which happens to be 4 units away from P...

Comment: The perpendicular distance formula is $|d| = \frac{ax_1+by_1+c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$ right? Plugging in the values (for the point $(13,8)$) it becomes $4 = \frac{13a+8b+c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$ How can this be solved to get the slope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intersection of the two lines is not $(13,4)$.  Plugging that point into the first line gives $8$ and into the second gives $4$ for the left hand side, not $0$, so you need to redo the solution for the point.  The $x$ coordinate is correct, but not $y$.  Then there are many lines through that point and you are to use the distance information to pick two of them.  If the intersection point is $(a,b)$, the point slope formula would be $y-b=m(x-a)$ and you need to use your formula for the distance between $(1,4)$ and this line to pick $m$.

Added:  I meant the line through $(13,8)$ of slope $m$, so $y-8=m(x-13)$ or $-mx+y+13m-8=0$.  You need the distance from $(1,4)$ to this line to be $4$.  [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance2-Dimensional.html) gives the distance from the point $(x_0,y_0)$ to the line $ax+by+c=0$ as $\frac{|ax_0+by_0+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$ so you have $4=\frac{|-m+4+13m-8|}{\sqrt{m^2+1}}$.  Moving the $\sqrt{m^2+1}$ to the other side and squaring, you should find two values for $m$.

Comment: Yes that was a mistake, I corrected it. Thanks :)

Comment: _you need to use your formula for the distance between (1,4) and this line to pick $m$._ Which line are you referring to here? and which formula to get $m$?

Comment: If you meant that $y-4=m(x-1)$, this becomes $mx-y+4-m=0$ and then use the perpendicular distance formula between this line and the point $(1,4)$, it becomes $4 = \frac{m-4+4-m}{\sqrt{m^2+1}}$, there are no solutions for this. $4 = \frac{0}{\sqrt{m^2+1}}$ and $4 = 0$ which is not true

Comment: Thank you Ross, this helped and I got the correct answers :)